# Setting code to maximum width of 80 characters

Tags: code-organization

Are there any websites than can automatically set large chunks of code (PHP, JS and CSS) to a maximum width of 80 characters to ensure that no lines wrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cloud9](https://c9.io/) IDE has this feature. It's in the View menue I think, you have to unselect wrap lines to viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `ch` unit described [in the CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths):

> Equal to the used advance measure of the "0" (ZERO, U+0030) glyph found in the font used to render it.

Thus `max-width: 80ch` limits the width to 80 characters.